# Easy way to call stored procedure in Java

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

When call a stored procedure I use this code:

```
    connection = getConnection();
    stmt = connection.prepareCall("{call MPLOGIN (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)}");
    stmt.setString("VUSCD", uscd);
    stmt.setString("VPWD", pwd);
    stmt.setString("VPCSQ", pcsq);
    stmt.setString("VHWID", hwid);
    stmt.registerOutParameter("VLOGID", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
    stmt.registerOutParameter("VKQ", OracleTypes.VARCHAR);
    stmt.execute();
    String vlogid = stmt.getString("VLOGID");
    String vkq = stmt.getString("VKQ");
```

write this boring wrapper for few procedure is not problem but if there are hundreds of procedure, it is really a nightmare
Is there any easier way to call store procedure than this way?
Edit: I think a code generator which use the procedure's parameters from DB is the elagant way but I google for nothing in java

Comment: There isn't any other way.

Comment: You could try use Spring JDBC stored procedure wrapper (http://rockycode.com/blog/stored-procedure-spring-jdbc/) may be yo will like it more

Comment: Considered asking the database administrators to run a "generate java wrapper" script every time they update a store procedure?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen does the "generate java wrapper" script exist? or  must be create by myself?

Comment: @yelliver somebody has to write something - strongly depends on how the stored procedures are programmed.  You most likely need to use a bit of elbow grease here.  There unfortunately is a bit of grunt work involved whenever you need to link systems together.

Answer (score 2):

You could, maybe create a generic wrapper, something along these lines:

```
public Map<String, String> SPWrapper(String call, Map<String, String> inParams, Map<String, OracleTypes> outParams)
{
    connection = getConnection();
    try 
    {
        stmt = connection.prepareCall(call);
        for(String inParam : inParams.keys())
        {
            stmt.setString(inParam, inParams.get(inParam));
        }
        for(String outParam : outParams.keys())
        {
            stmt.registerOutParameter(outParam, outParams.get(outParam));
        }

        stmt.execute();

        Map<String,String> results = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(String outParam : outParams.keys())
        {
            results.put(outParam, stmt.getString(outParam));
        }

        return results;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        //LOG Exception
        return new HashMap<String, String>();
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.close();   //Do not leave connections open.
    }
}
```

You would still need to pass in the `call` and declare the variables, but at least you now have one generic wrapper to handle all your calls.

Comment: I really thinked about this way, but imagine that when you call in practice, seem like this:
`HashMap<String, String> inMap = HashMap<String, String>();
HashMap<String, String> outMap = HashMap<String, String>();

inMap.put("VUSCD", uscd);
inMap.put("VPWD", pwd);
inMap.put("VPCSQ", pcsq);
inMap.put("VHWID", hwid);`


setting value for inMap is as weird as the normal way :(

Comment: @yelliver: No better option comes to mind. The advantage of the method I propose is that you just need to declare one code segment which handles everything, you would just need to take care of the calls. You could just declare two HashMaps and clear them between calls, this could make the code look less weird, but I think that you would still, at some point define the parameter names and values.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use the [MyBatis](http://code.google.com/p/mybatis/) data mapper framework for such problems. An extensive example for working with MyBatis and stored procedures can be found at http://loianegroner.com/2011/03/ibatis-mybatis-working-with-stored-procedures/

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any other way. Yes, it is boring, but number of procedures is finite. This procedures are like methods in Java, so you should operate with them in prescribed rules. 
Only one convenient thing you could do - create special class, which will contain wrapped methods for each procedure. In this case it will be more elegantly to call them in business code, something like this:

```
String[] result = DAO.MPLOGIN(uscd, pwd, pcsq, hwid);
```

But inside this method you have to copy code, that you mentioned above.

Comment: Maybe it would even be possible to auto-generate this DAO wrapper class with a script.

Comment: @Philipp, Yes I agree. But it is more complicated issue :)

Comment: This generator could be hand-made written, but its implementation depends on concrete DataBase.

Answer (score 0):

In database client a stored procedure such as myproc(10,20) is called just by statement

```sql
select myproc(10,20);
```

So in your JDBC program you can just do :

```java
connection = getConnection();
stmt = connection.createStatement();
stmt.executeQuery("select myproc(10,20)");
```

If procedure is returning something then put it in a ResultSet

Comment: Its just a String. Manipulating the string can get the procedure called with any arguments,that are valid though...

Answer (score 0):

[jOOQ includes a code generator that generates stubs for all of your PL/SQL packages, types, procedures, functions](https://blog.jooq.org/the-best-way-to-call-stored-procedures-from-java-with-jooq/). In your case, you could avoid the boring boiler plate code by calling this stub, instead:

```java
Mplogin result = Routines.mplogin(
    configuration, // This contains your JDBC connection
    uscd, pwd, pcsq, hwid
);

String vlogid = result.getVlogid();
String vkq = result.getVkq();
```

Disclaimer: I work for the company behind jOOQ.